# How can I get a mortgage I can't afford?

Tags: mortgage, united-kingdom

There is a house that we are really keen on buying.

So, I went along to a mortgage advisor who did some quick checks and he came to the conclusion that the house was about £10k more than any mortgage company would be willing to lend to us.

Now I know that we could afford the repayments for our house since the repayments for the price of that house are roughly what our rent comes to now.

Is there anything we can do to either push up our affordability or find someone who is willing to lend a little bit more?

Comment: The bank is factoring other things that you obviously aren't.  When renting you don't have a lot of the costs that come with home ownership such as insurance, taxes, maintenance, etc.

Comment: @Kevin: If the landlord has structured it correctly, the rent is covering the cost of insurance, taxes and maintenance. Though if the mortgage is old, the mortgage payment for the landlord could be very low.

Comment: Will you still be able to afford the payment when interest rates rise?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam In the US, many mortgages are fixed-rate mortgages while many others are adjustable-rate mortgages.  Are _all_ mortgages in the UK adjustable rate mortgages? Or are both types offered?

Comment: Fixed rate mortgages are common, but the typical fix length is 2-5 years, rather than the entire mortgage term. Longer fixes do exist but are rare. So it's likely that the question of a rate change will arise at some point.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam We can get a 5 year fixed rate mortgage. Over which time I will have salary increases, savings from side projects etc..

Comment: @Mongus: Unfortunately you don't know for sure that you'll get raises, and the bank is probably factoring in the risks of you losing your job and such.  Not to mention your raises might not be more than inflation, might not cover rate increases, etc.

Comment: @Telos true, they are not going to factor my confidence in their risk assessment. However, I will, otherwise I would just accept the banks first answer and walk away.

Comment: It obviously depends on your job, but in the current climate I am certainly not counting on even inflation-linked pay rises over the next 5 years.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Honestly I would look for a house you can afford and one that is below the maximum amount of what they are willing to lend you.

The reason is owning a house is not a quick loan that you can pay off in a year or two (unless you're rich then I would question why are you even bothering with a loan). This is a long term commitment; can you honestly say your job will provide the money for the mortgage, the upkeep and remodeling of the house (even if it's the perfect house you will want to change something, make the bathroom bigger, put in a pool table etc.. etc..), living expenses and any hiccups life throws at you?

Like most of us, that answer will be no. Always have money and supplies for that rainy day, for those lean days. For that mortgage payment. And if nothing happens you can always use the money to pay the mortgage off faster or take a vacation.

Comment: +1 - my own answer focused on getting him the loan. You are correct to try to talk him out of it. Welcome to SE, by the way!

Comment: Yes good point. Although we can afford the rent, any house repairs etc.. just get passed on to our landlord. We would have to swallow these ourselves when owning.

Comment: @MongusPong Exactly. The costs of owning a home are **far** more than just the mortgage. Don't forget property tax, PMI if needed, association fees, homeowner's insurance, lawn/snow care if applicable, repairs, higher utilities, and more. I'd guess our mortgage is less than half of our total cost of home ownership.

Comment: @Steven, "lawn/snow care if applicable"...No wonder no one can afford to buy a houes these days, we have all become so lazy that we have to pay others to take care of cutting and maintaining our lawn! Years ago we used to do most of our own house maintenance ourselves, these days we pay an electrician to change a light bulb for us.

Comment: @Victor Not everyone is healthy enough to perform physically-demanding home care. Not everyone has time (after working multiple jobs). Some neighborhoods have mandatory associations fees for lawn/snow care. And some people would rather spend time with their family than mowing the lawn. I said "if applicable" for a reason: please be civil and don't assume laziness.

Comment: @Steven, I am talking about abled people who have plenty of time on their hands, but rather pay someone else to do some work around the house. Regarding spending time with the family, I used to enjoy the times I spent helping my dad around the garden and home in my pre-teen and teen years. You don't have to go out to spend time with the family, you can do it by doing things around the house, things that will improve the house and pass on skills from the parent to the child.

Comment: @Victor, it is perfectly reasonable for someone to value their free time at a higher rate than the rate they would pay to have some menial labor done for them.

Comment: @Joviee, that is fine, but for them to then complain that they can't aford this or can't afford that, then maybe they should be looking at the things they are spending their money on and why they can't afford essential. It is also funny how someone will go to work and work hard for their employer for $20 or $25 or $30 per hour, but then will pay someone $50 to cut their lawn in less than one hour. That may be the reason why so many are crying poor!

Comment: @Victor - or, I could pay the $50 to have my lawn cut, and hop on my computer and earn about $150 in the same time. The fact is, though, nobody wants to spend every waking hour working. At some point, free time becomes more valuable than a few extra dollars. This does not make people lazy, or entitled, or financially incompetent. It makes them human.

Comment: @Joviee, if you can hop on your computer and earn $150 in less than one hour, then you wouldn't have to go to work 40+ hours per week would you and you would theoretically have plenty of free time. The point I am making is that you need to live within your means, and if you get paid under $30 per hour at work it makes no sense to pay someone to cut your lawn if you are struggling to pay other bills. If you get paid $150 per hour, then it makes plenty of sense to pay someone $50 to cut your lawn. It is just that those earning less than $30/hr want to be like those earning $150+/hr.

Comment: @Victor, actually, your original point was just complaining about "lazy" people paying to have menial labor done, rather than doing it themselves. You only started shifting the goalposts to "living within your means" once Steven and myself offered up a number of examples where paying for menial labor to be performed makes sense. Either way, neither your comments nor my comments are constructive/useful at this point, so should probably be deleted :) Last post for me.

Comment: @Joviee, my point from the start to the end has been about people who can't aford it, paying for things that they could do themselves.

Comment: With the house we are looking at you could probably mow the lawn with a pair of scissors in 5 minutes.

Comment: One quibble:  It's possible to have a situation where getting a mortgage makes sense despite being in a position to pay it off in a year or two.  Sometimes there are other factors that say buy now rather than in the year or two when you could pay cash.

Answer (score 10):

- Get a private loan from friend/family
- If possible, borrow the funds from your retirement account (in US, this is a low cost way, not sure how your retirement plans work.)
- Find someone to rent a room in the new house, if you bring the lender a signed lease, they should count a portion of it as income, a few hundred £/mo should cover the 10K you are short.
- Stop spending. If you are truly this close, stop all discretionary spending. No cable TV, no eating out, I mean go "rice and beans" to save that up.
- As OrionDarkwood suggested in comment - Talk seller down by £10K, I don't know if you are looking at a £100K house or £200K, so £10K may not be that high a percent.
- Ask the seller to finance the extra. Sometimes the bank will have a limit, but still allow the seller to finance a second note after the mortgage.
- Ask the realtor (real estate broker) to chip in. In the US, they can take 6%. When a deal is very close, they will often give up 2% to close the deal and move on rather than lose the sale.
- Approach your current boss(es) and discuss a raise.
- Earn extra money. A friend here documented his second job in [Deliver Away Debt.](http://deliverawaydebt.com/) He took on a second job delivering pizza on Friday and Saturday nights. (The point is not about pizza, it's about finding clever ways to raise money. £10k might take 1000 hours to earn, maybe less.)
- Combine elements above. A small raise, a few months of second job, etc.

You might also want to talk directly to a bank. If your credit report is clean, they may have some discretion in making the loan.

Note - the 'normal' fully qualified loan has two thresholds, 28% (of monthly income) for housing costs, 36% for all debt servicing. A personal, disclosed loan from a friend/family which is not secured against the house, would count as part of the other debt, as would a credit card. While I don't recommend using a credit card for this purpose, the debt fits in that 28-36 gap.

As Kevin points out below, not all paths are equally advisable. Nor are rules of thumb always true. Not having the OP's full details, income, assets, price of house, etc, this is just a list of things to consider. The use of a 401(k) loan in the US can be a great idea for some, bad mistake for others. This format doesn't make it easy to go into great detail, and I'm sure the 401(k) loan issue has been asked and answered in other questions. With respect to Kevin, if he wrote 'usually', I'd agree, but never say 'never.'

Comment: I would also add, not sure how things work in the UK (I am assuming this due to the use of pounds as a currency). But have you tried to see if you can talk the seller down in price?

Comment: With regard to getting a private loan, that does not help (at least in the US) because the loan must be disclosed on the mortgage application, and the lender will definitely take that into account in deciding how much they are willing to loan on the house. After all, the private loan repayments also affect the cash flow of the borrower.  Also, it is kind of hard to lease a room in the new house before purchasing it! Finally, aren't lbs (pounds avoirdupois) different from the £ pounds sterling that the OP mentions?

Comment: @DilipSarwate He was talking about the tenant's weight. :D

Comment: @Chelonian If the prospective tenant does indeed weigh a few hundred pounds, the expense of re-inforcing the floor joists, staircase, etc is another item that should be included in the calculations! :-)

Comment: Ok, so even though it sounds like the same word, lbs is *not* the abbreviation for pounds sterling? Thanks for the funny lesson, I wont make that mistake again.

Comment: IMO this is the best answer. The OP wants the practical answer on how to overcome technically not being able to afford, not advice on whether he can really afford it. You could also add list: asking your current place of work for a raise or an opportunity to work overtime, moonlight for extra money for the next week, sell stuff that you have. Also consider simultaneously doing all of the tactics so far listed, don't focus on just one.

Comment: @Benedict - I'll add your other advice, but I respectfully disagree. I think we have an obligation to answer certain questions as we would to a child (I mean our grown children, not youngsters) or to our best friends. When someone phrases the question as OP did here, it invites a second look, and Orion's answer is the one I'd personally choose.

Comment: I don't get why this is getting upvotes.  Some of these are terrible suggestions.  NEVER borrow, or lend, money to friends or family.  Borrowing funds from retirement account is an equally bad idea.

Comment: Ha! There's a process of brainstorming in which one offers many ideas regardless of viability. You should see the ones I considered and dismissed. Respectfully, absolutes are rarely true. NEVER? No discussion of how much that friend needs, why he needs it, or how he took a bullet for you (literally or figuratively) years ago? Some take a retirement loan, and default after a job loss. Others use it to buy the house, paying less in the mortgage than the rent was, take in a roommate, and pay the loan off in under a year. One size does not fit all.

Answer (score 9):

Save up a bigger downpayment.

The lender's requirement is going to be based on how much you finance, not the price of the house.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't afford it don't buy it, the next perfect house is just around the corner. The more time you spend researching and looking at houses, the increased chance you will find the perfect house you can afford.

Also, here in Australia, we (the banks as well) factor in an interest rate rise of 2% above current rates to see if repayments can still be afforded at this increased rate.

Answer (score -1):

You can ask the buyer to lower the price by the amount you are approved for and negation transferring the amount to him via a escrow..